# can i make built-in vscode.html-language-features wrap tags like prettier does?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, format, prettier

What i'm try to format:
[Original code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSQmR.png)

How vscode.html-language-features wraps it:
[vscode.html-language-features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpdUE.png)

How prettier wraps it: [prettier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkfUc.png)